# Calculating the inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1\end{bmatrix} calculate the inverse.

I assumed this to be quite easy, as I'd just have to use the f act that A is row equivalent to $I_3$

So using the following matrix I attempted to solve it:

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1  & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

My first step was subtract `row 2` from `row 1` and add `row 3` to `row 2` which yields:

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1  & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Then I proceeded by removing `2 * row 3` from `row 1` and got:

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 1 & -1\\1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1  & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

But then I get stuck, because if I divide `row 1' by three I get $\frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{3} \frac{-1}{3}$. Yet this answer isn't part of the answers given.

According to the problem it should be:

$\begin{bmatrix} 1/3 & 2/3 & 1/3 \\ 1/3 & -1/3 & 1/3\\1/3 & -1/3 & -2/3 \end{bmatrix}$

Did I make a mistake somwhere?

Comment: You can stop when the left block is $I$.  You stopped too soon.

Comment: You have made a mistake in the first step while subtracting row 2 from row 1. Row 1 (the right side) then becomes 1 -1 0 not 1 1 0. Also in the step "row 1 - 2* row 3". Row 1 (on rhs again) becomes 1 -1 -2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should strive to get an upper triangular matrix on the left.

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1  & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Subtract row $1$ from row $2$.

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & -2 & -1 & -1 & 1  & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Change places between row $2$ and $3$.

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\0  & -2 & -1 & -1 & 1  & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Add $2$ times row $2$ to row $3$.

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\0  & 0 & -3 & -1 & 1  & 2\end{bmatrix}$

Divide row $3$ by $-3$.

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\0  & 0 & 1 & 1/3 & -1/3  & -2/3\end{bmatrix}$

Add row $3$ to row $2$.

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 1/3 & -1/3 & 1/3 \\0  & 0 & 1 & 1/3 & -1/3  & -2/3\end{bmatrix}$

Subtract row $3$ from row $1$.

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 2/3 & 1/3 & 2/3\\0 & 1 & 0 & 1/3 & -1/3 & 1/3 \\0  & 0 & 1 & 1/3 & -1/3  & -2/3\end{bmatrix}$

Subtract row $2$ from row $1$.

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 & 2/3 & 1/3\\0 & 1 & 0 & 1/3 & -1/3 & 1/3 \\0  & 0 & 1 & 1/3 & -1/3  & -2/3\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1/3 & 2/3 & 1/3\\1/3 & -1/3 & 1/3 \\ 1/3 & -1/3  & -2/3\end{bmatrix}$